# Where is the Microsoft.Windows.Controls.dll in the Nov 2009 Silverlight Toolkit?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-toolkit, wrappanel

I want to use **WrapPanel** in Silverlight 3.

It is apparently in the Silverlight **Toolkit**.

All the information I can find on it say to download the toolkit, unzip the download, look in the folder binaries and you will find **Microsoft.Windows.Controls.dll**.

This **works** for [December 2008](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/19172) version of the Silverlight toolkit just fine, since it is a zip file.

But I would like the **newest** version.

However, the [November 2009](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/36060) version of the Silverlight toolkit is an **.msi** file which installs but doesn't tell me where **Microsoft.Windows.Controls.dll** is.

Nor is it in the Add Service | .NET tab.

**How can I get the Microsoft.Windows.Controls.dll from the November 2009 Silverlight Toolkit install so I can use WrapPanel in Silverlight 3?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I installed it I didn't change any defaults and it's installed to:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Toolkit\Nov09\Bin

But I can't see a Microsoft.Windows.Controls.dll in that folder.

As far I as can ascertain you want **System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll**

Comment: yes, that's it, and System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit is actually available under the .NET tab under that name, so in the end no need to go to the directory, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The DLLs for the toolkit are located at:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Toolkit\Nov09\Bin

(though, as someone else mentioned, that *particular* DLL isn't available)

They should also be available if you Add a Reference as well. Just look under the .Net tab (when you have a Silverlight Project open).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.Windows.Controls had been changed to System.Windows.Controls

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20March%202009%20change%20list&ProjectName=silverlight

Answer (score 0):

The controls in the silverlight toolkit use to be in the microsoft.windows.controls.dll.  The March 2009 version of the toolkit moved the controls to system.windows.controls.dll

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20March%202009%20change%20list